# Blender 2.77 Unwrapping a mirrored object (Pre-existing texture)

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers, mirror

Ok going to rewrite my question as it was a bit confusing.

I took .obj shirt that has a existing uv/bump map, and cut it in half along the X axis. I then mirrored the shirt so that I could Edit one side only and have the other be an exact duplicate.

As you can see in the below image, the uv texture is now sharing the same area for both sides since I did a mirror.

My question:
Are there any methods that I could:

1. Unwrap the object and generate a new texture based off of what is already assigned/attached to the .obj? (ie so that the vertex faces no longer overlap each other, and are separated to there own sides, but also morphing the texture as well)
2. "Glue" the attached texture to the .obj so that when I do a unwrap, the texture also follows the unwrap. (texture follows the new vertex coordinates of the unwrap)

[image]

Maybe there is another 3d texture software that might be able to do what I am trying to achieve?